# Python Dash Bootstrap Components - Change Icon Color

Tags: python, css

I am trying to build my first Dash Web Application with Python.

I am using some Dash Bootstrap Components.
Right now I'm struggling with adjusting the Icon to my needs.
For example I have some [dbc.AccordionItem's](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/accordion/).
They have an Icon on the right hand site. As far as I know it is called '[Chevron Down](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/chevron-down/)'.

I would like to adjust the color from black to white but I don't know how to do that and I can't find the Icon in the source code of the web application.

The Part of the Accordion Item looks like this:

```html
<div class="infoItemTop accordion-item"><h2 class="accordion-header" style="margin-top: 0rem; margin-bottom: 0rem;"><button type="button" aria-expanded="true" class="accordion-button">Objektklassen</button></h2><div class="accordion-collapse collapse show" style=""><div class="accordion-body"><p id="corePlusI">Core Plus: 8.09%</p><p id="coreI">Core: 7.57%</p><p id="valueAddI">Value-Add: 27.96%</p><p id="opportunistischI">Opportunistisch: 23.97%</p></div></div></div>
<h2 class="accordion-header" style="margin-top: 0rem; margin-bottom: 0rem;"><button type="button" aria-expanded="true" class="accordion-button">Objektklassen</button></h2>
<button type="button" aria-expanded="true" class="accordion-button">Objektklassen</button>
Objektklassen
<<pseudo>></<pseudo>>
<button type="button" aria-expanded="true" class="accordion-button">Objektklassen</button>
<h2 class="accordion-header" style="margin-top: 0rem; margin-bottom: 0rem;"><button type="button" aria-expanded="true" class="accordion-button">Objektklassen</button></h2>
<div class="accordion-collapse collapse show" style="">...</div></div>
```